# Install Mac OS 10.4.11 on Intel

Tags: macos, mac, osx-tiger

I'm looking for advice on how to install 10.4.11 on an Intel Mac for testing purposes.  I don't have an Intel 10.4.11 CD.  I have an ADC account but only see a 10.4 PPC dmg and 10.4.11 update dmg.

Comment: Why don't you ask Apple?

Answer (score 1):

Find a Mac repair store near you and purchase/obtain a Tiger Intel install disk from a iBook or iMac. Use that to install, then Software Update to get up to 10.4.11.

Comment: I have a Tiger install disk but the early ones are PPC only and I don't think that will install in an Intel Mac to allow an upgrade.  I am also don't know if one can upgrade a PPP 10.4 to an Intel 10.4.

Comment: That's why I said to find an "Tiger Intel" disk from a repair store.

Comment: I misspoke about ibook and imac. They were ppc. The first gen macbook's where Tiger 10.4. In any event, the local mac repair guy will have disks available.

Answer (score 0):

10.4 will only work on an Intel Mac if that Mac model came with 10.4 originally, in which case hopefully you kept the DVDs...

Anyway, if you don't have them, you will need to look for someone who has the same model Mac as you and get a copy of their restore DVDs. 10.4 for Intel was never available as a "retail" disc suitable for multiple models of Mac.

Comment: Shouldn't that read: "10.4 DVDs that came with some Mac cannot be used on another kind of Mac"? As far as I can tell, 10.4 was also available in a retail version: http://www.google.com/products?q=10.4+retail+dvd